# How to handle errors exception in laravel snappyPDF?

Tags: php, laravel

Using Laravel/Snappy to generate PDFs. However this errors:

> already exist file name after trying to save it to storage.

How can I handle these errors?

```
public function saveSnappyHeaderFooter()
{

    //dd( storage_path());
    $users = \App\User::all();
    $data = ['users' => $users]; 
    $SnappyPDF = SnappyPDF::loadView('pdf.snappyPDF.snappyHeaderFooter', $data);
    $SnappyPDF->setOption('margin-top', '25mm');
    $SnappyPDF->setOption('margin-bottom', '25mm');
    $SnappyPDF->setOption('header-html', public_path() . '\pdf-parts\pdf-header.html');
    $SnappyPDF->setOption('footer-html', public_path() . '\pdf-parts\pdf-footer.html');
    $SnappyPDF->setOption('print-media-type', true);


    $SnappyPDF->save(storage_path('app/files/'.Carbon::now() .'_' . 'myname2.pdf'));

}
```

Comment: "The output file 'C:\xampp\htdocs\auth_with_role_middleware\storage\app\files\01_04_2019_myname2.pdf' already exists."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general this is how you can handle errors in PHP:

```
 try {
        //your code
    } catch (Exception $e) {

      //handle errors

    }
```

Or you can ask if file exists by using:

```
if(!file_exists(storage_path('app/files/'.Carbon::now() .'_' . 'myname2.pdf'))){
    //ok, code will run
}else{
   // not ok, maybe change the name?
}
```

you can also do it in the laravel way: `File::exists`

Or maybe you can give us more details.

**Note**
Its an anti-patteren to not be 100% sure that the files is not exists. I dont know your usecase, but im saying that based on the fact that you are generating the file name. maybe you should use more uniq patterens. like GUIDs...